# With Google Maps APIs, display map that's bounded by {minLat, min Long} and {maxLat, maxLong}

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-api-2

Google Maps APIs require 3 parameters to start with: lat, long and zoom level.  What I want is to determine the closest zoom level based on the min lat, min long, max lat, and max long, so that my map can be displayed at the right scale, no more and no less.  What's an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use bounds to fit your map.

```
bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
bounds.extend(minLatLng);
bounds.extend(maxLatLng);
map.fitBounds(bounds);
```